# How do I pronounce some possessive forms of words whose pronunciations end with s?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives

The examples come below.

- Sussex's
- Case's
- anus's

How do I pronounce them?

Comment: This is really a question for English Language Learners, not here.

Comment: crocket, just so you know what Hot Licks was talking about, you can ask questions like this at the following site: http://ell.stackexchange.com